# Not a native Intel OpenCL runtime. Expect massive speed loss

Tags: hash, passwords, hashcat

I am trying to use Hashcat but I am getting this error. I searched online and tried everything (such as installing apt-get install ocl-icd-libopencl1 opencl-headers clinfo) but the same error is happening.

[image]